# How to sort array data as per key value using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array which contains json data as per some key value. I am providing my array below.

```
$data=[
{device_type:"1",hit_type:"3",member_id:"96",name:"Gallery",rest_name:"Goro + Gun",summery_id:"22"},
{device_type:"1",hit_type:"1",member_id:"96",name:"Page",rest_name:"Goro + Gun",summery_id:"22"},
{device_type:"1",hit_type:"2",member_id:"96",name:"Map",rest_name:"Goro + Gun",summery_id:"22"},
{device_type:"1",hit_type:"2",member_id:"96",name:"Map",rest_name:"Goro + Gun",summery_id:"22"},
{device_type:"1",hit_type:"4",member_id:"90",name:"Phone",rest_name:"the livingroom",summery_id:"21"},
]
```

I have the array of data which is given above. I need to sort this as per `member_id` and counts the `hit_type` and `total hit` finally it need to save into another array. My expected output array is given below.

```
$result=[
{device_type:"1",member_id:"96",Page_hit:"1",Gallery_hit:"1",Map_hit:"2",Phone_hit:"0",Web_hit:"0",rest_name:"Goro + Gun",summery_id:"22",total_hit:"4"},
{device_type:"1",member_id:"90",Page_hit:"0",Gallery_hit:"0",Map_hit:"0",Phone_hit:"1",Web_hit:"0",rest_name:"the livingroom",summery_id:"21",total_hit:"1"}
]
```

The above is my expected output.hit_type will always count as per member_id and the table is given below.

```
name      type
Page       1
Map        2
Gallery    3
Phone      4
Web        5
```

Edit: The query from the comments:

```
$sql = "
SELECT s.summery_id,
       s.member_id,
       s.hit_type,
       s.device_type,
       s.counter,
       s.date,
       r.rest_name,
       h‌​.NAME,
       h.type
FROM   db_analytics_summery AS s
       LEFT JOIN db_hit_type AS h
              ON s.hit_type = h.type
       LEFT JOIN db_restaurant_basic AS r
              ON s.member_id = r.member_id
ORDER  BY s.summery_id DESC;
";
```

Comment: is  it from DataBase?

Comment: Yes,I can fetch the 1st array from DB.

Comment: I started reading this and thought it was a duplicate of the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value but reading data from a database and then sorting it is exceptionally silly. Use the database for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in query

```
SELECT s.device_type,
   s.member_id,
   sum(if(`hit_type`=1,1,0)) Page_hit,
   sum(if(`hit_type`=3,1,0)) Gallery_hit,
   ...
   r.rest_name,
   count(1) total_hit
 FROM   db_analytics_summery AS s
   LEFT JOIN db_hit_type AS h
          ON s.hit_type = h.type
   LEFT JOIN db_restaurant_basic AS r
          ON s.member_id = r.member_idgroup by
 group by member_id
 ORDER  BY s.summery_id DESC;
```

Comment: I have this query `$sql="select s.summery_id,s.member_id,s.hit_type,s.device_type,s.counter,s.date,r.rest_name,h.name,h.type";
  $sql.=" from db_analytics_summery as s";
  $sql.=" left join db_hit_type as h on s.hit_type=h.type";
  $sql.=" left join db_restaurant_basic as r on s.member_id=r.member_id";
  $sql.=" order by s.summery_id desc";
  $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);`.

Comment: Can you edit here so that i can get my expected out put as explained above.

Comment: @spalsh,Is this two line(`sum(if(`hit_type`=1,1,0)) Page_hit,
   sum(if(`hit_type`=3,1,0)) Gallery_hit,`) are right ?

Comment: i tried your answer but its not coming as per my requirement.Each time count of hit type is showing 0.

Comment: Glad that could help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again splash.